# Deploying a meteor 1.2 app to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I have an app that is still at meteor 1.2 that I used to deploy to ubuntu 14.04 servers happily with mup. However, I have now moved the host server along to 16.04 and mup (as well as mupc) have stopped working.

The last time I deployed one of these apps I followed the procedure below and it worked fine.

```
apt install nodejs nodejs-legacy
install nvm
nvm install v0.10.40

Bundle the app on my dev box, and unpack it on the host
cd /app/programs/server
npm install
```

and I get

```
> fibers@1.0.5 install /opt/sapwfdashboard/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

(node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
internal/child_process.js:298
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at build (/opt/sapwfdashboard/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build.js:55:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/sapwfdashboard/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build.js:47:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-109-generic
npm ERR! command "/root/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /opt/sapwfdashboard/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm stuck. Any idea how to get around this. I am going to have to upgrade this app as the initial deployments are just impossible now.

Comment: You have to install the same node version on your server as your local Meteor system uses. Check on your dev machine `meteor node -v` which gives you the correct version. Install this version on your server.

Comment: Try `nvm use v0.10.40` before you `npm install`

Comment: I'd already done that as can be seen from the versions in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to deploy this is to use mupc to set up the instances, and then use the manual deployment process from there onwards.

I'm still to work out what the differences are.